# Does this snippet of code(a macro for container traverse) works? if yes, why?

Tags: c++, macros, containers

Following Dmitry Korolev tutorial on TopCoder i encountered this generic-container-traverse macro:

```
#define tr(c,i) for(typeof((c).begin() i = (c).begin(); i != (c).end(); i++)
```

It confuses me because it appears to be missing a parenthesis. And in the explanation he says that typeof(...) is replaced by the type of the expression (...) , which makes me more confused with this traverse macro (since my intuition sees typeof (x ; y ; z) and would not
work since x;y;z is not a expression and even if it worked typeof(...) would "eat" the (...)).

Does it work? why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
#define tr(container, it) \ 
 for(typeof(container.begin()) it = container.begin(); \ 
                               it != container.end(); \
                                it++
    )
```

This is what [he has written](http://www.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=standardTemplateLibrary) which is syntactically correct. BTW `typeof` is a gcc extension and won't work in other compilers.

If your compiler supports C++0x you might want to use [`auto`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++0x#Type_inference)

For example the same macro can be written in C++0x as

```
#define tr(container, it) \ 
 for(auto it = container.begin(); \ 
          it != container.end(); \
          it++
    )
```

Comment: thanks! C++0x looks great, but i guess most competition judges do not use it yet. But most of them use gcc/g++ so i will be using the first version.

Answer (score 1):

It's a typo. Should be:

```
#define tr(c,i) for(typeof((c).begin()) i = (c).begin(); i != (c).end(); i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

It would work fine if there was an extra paren after `typeof((c).begin()`. I don't know what the original source was, but if it was actually missing a paren, the original person who put it probably typed it wrong.

```
#define tr(c,i) for(typeof((c).begin()) i = (c).begin(); i != (c).end(); i++)
```

Can be used in place of the top line of a for loop over a container. eg:

```
tr(myvector, i)
{
    std::cout << *i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong. It should be:

```
#define tr(c,i) for(typeof((c).begin()) i = (c).begin(); i != (c).end(); i++)
```